# Exporting data from a table using the BCP utility

Tags: sql, vbscript

I'm trying to export data from a table to a CSV file in an automated fashion, hence the VBScript.

Here is my code and error below:

```
bcp dbname "SELECT * FROM mytable" queryout C:\Test.csv -T -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sdbservername
```

[image: http://puu.sh/jIhtr/02b89c22af.png]

Comment: Is that your whole script? VBScript is not a batch file. If you want to run a command-line utility, you'll need to do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `bcp` but it looks like a command-line utility. If you want to execute that from a VBScript, you'll need to use `WshShell.Run`, as in the following example:

```vb
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    .Run "bcp dbname ""SELECT * FROM mytable"" queryout C:\Test.csv -T -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sdbservername"

End With
```

Take note of the doubled quotes around your SQL statement.

Comment: This worked like magic.  For reference, the final bcp code i used to complete this was the following     bcp "SELECT id FROM mytable" queryout C:\Test.csv -T -c -E -S servername -d dbname

Answer (score 1):

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM mytable" queryout "C:\Test.csv" -T -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sdbservername
```

You should not have dbname after `bcp`. I removed it. This should work.

Comment: Hmm, still getting a expected end of statement on char 38 which is after "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

Comment: try selecting column names explicitly instead of `*`

Comment: Same, expected end of statement after the "query"

Comment: are you including a `space` after `-UUsername` and others? it should be `-U username -P password -S servername`